# Weird behavior in referring to global variable. Is this a bug in javascript? Surely it isn't!

Tags: javascript, variables

Consider the following piece of code.

```
<html>
<body>
<script>  
var x = 5; //globally declared
function showX() 
{ 
      alert("x="+x); //trying to display global value

      var x=10; //trying to create and initialize a local x
}
</script>
<input type = "button" value="Show X" onclick="showX()"> 
</body>
</html>
```

The alert statement shows 'x=undefined'. And doesn't print the global value of x as expected. An equivalent java code would display 5! So, is it a bug? If not then how does one explain that behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [ECMAScript Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) says in section 12.2:

> If the variable statement occurs
>   inside a FunctionDeclaration, the
>   variables are defined with
>   function-local scope in that function,
>   as described in s10.1.3. Otherwise,
>   they are defined with global scope
>   (that is, they are created as members
>   of the global object, as described in
>   10.1.3) using property attributes { DontDelete}. Variables are created
>   when the execution scope is entered. A
>   Block does not define a new execution
>   scope. Only Program and
>   FunctionDeclaration produce a new
>   scope. Variables are initialised to
>   undefined when created. A variable
>   with an Initialiser is assigned the
>   value of its AssignmentExpression when
>   the VariableStatement is executed, not
>   when the variable is created.

So it's not a bug - the local variable is created when the function is entered.

Comment: The ECMAScript Specification's excerpt that you have provided explains it very clearly. But, got to admit that the mechanism creates confusing situation like the one discussed in the question!

Answer (score 2):

The second var-declaration is interfering with the first. You are actually referring to the as-of-yet-undeclared local x. However, to quote javascript guru Douglas Crockford:

> JavaScript's biggest problem is its
>   dependence on global variables,
>   particularly implied global variables.
>   If a variable is not explicitly
>   declared (usually with the var
>   statement), then JavaScript assumes
>   that the variable was global. This can
>   mask misspelled names and other
>   problems.

http://www.jslint.com/lint.html

So the recommendation is to avoid using global variables as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

The scope of `x` is the <strike>block</strike> function in which it is declared... although I believe scope in JavaScript can be a bit tricky sometimes. In C# this would be a compile-time error - it would be trying to use the local variable before its declaration.

Whatever the reason, I'd try to avoid doing it simply for the sake of readability.